# Transposing in MS-excel with condition to rows values into Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have data into Excel like bellow,
[image]

with the reference of above excel data, I want to filter data from Sheet1 to sheet2 like following.

[image].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose Column into Row with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48222495/transpose-column-into-row-with-vba)

Answer (score 2):

Without VBA (always better IMO):

```
=INDEX(
$B$1:$E$8,
MATCH($B12,$B$1:$B$8,0)+QUOTIENT(COLUMN(),3)-COLUMN($B$1)+1,
MOD(COLUMN(),3)+COLUMN($B$1)
)
```

Setup as follows:

1. Type the formula in C12
2. Stretch the formula right and down

[image]

Answer (score 1):

one of the possible variants:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim x&, Z%, cl As Range
    x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print (TypeName(Z))
    For Each cl In Range("A2:A" & x)
        append = cl.Offset(, 1) & "|" & cl.Offset(, 2) & "|" & cl.Offset(, 3)
        If Not Dic.exists(UCase(cl.Value2)) Then
            Dic.Add UCase(cl.Value2), append
        Else
            Dic(UCase(cl.Value2)) = Dic(UCase(cl.Value2)) & "|" & append
        End If
    Next cl
    Workbooks.Add
    x = 2
    For Each d In Dic
        Z = UBound(Split(Dic(d), "|")) + 1
        Cells(x, "A") = d: Cells(x, "B").Resize(, Z) = Split(Dic(d), "|")
        x = x + 1
    Next d
End Sub
```

test:

source:

[image]

result:

[image]